# Iteration variable goes out of range in for-loop

Tags: c++

I have a for-loop in my function:

```cpp
for (int i = vector1.size() - 1, j = vector2.size() - 1;i >= vector1.size() - Get_polynomial_power(vector1) - 1;--i, --j) {
   // some code
   something = vector1.at(i); // <- here i goes out of range
}
```

The problem is that iteration variable `i` goes out of range.

Condition for exiting from loop is set with `i >= vector1.size() - Get_polynomial_power(vector1) - 1;` which equals to `i >= 0` in my specific case (`Get_polynomial_power` is user defined function that returns some `int` value).

And the last value of `i` is `-1`. So the program terminates with thrown exception "out of range".

**But** if I set condition for exiting the loop directly with `0`, so it looks like:

```cpp
for (int i = vector1.size() - 1, j = vector2.size() - 1;i >= 0;--i, --j) {
   // some code
   something = vector1.at(i); // <- here i doesn't go out of range
}
```

then there is no error and the last value of `i` is `0` so it doesn't go out of range.

So **the question** is: why doesn't iteration variable goes out of range if condition for exit from loop is set directly via `0`, but if it is set with a statement that is equals to `0` then the error appears?

I tried a solution with loop-local value as was told in other similar questions, like:

```cpp
for (int i = vector1.size() - 1, j = vector2.size() - 1;i >= vector1.size() - Get_polynomial_power(vector1) - 1;--i, --j) {
   // some code
   int index = i;
   something = vector1.at(index);
}
```

but it didn't change the thing.

Just in case, here is full code of my function:

```cpp
vector<int> Polynomial_addition_substraction(vector<int> polynomial1, vector<int> polynomial2) {
  vector<int> addition_substraction_result;
  vector<int> vector1;
  vector<int> vector2;
  if (Get_polynomial_power(polynomial1) >= Get_polynomial_power(polynomial2)) {
    vector1 = polynomial1;
    vector2 = polynomial2;
  }
  else {
    vector1 = polynomial2;
    vector2 = polynomial1;
  }
  for (int i = vector1.size() - 1, j = vector2.size() - 1;i>=vector1.size()-Get_polynomial_power(vector1)-1;--i,--j) {
    if (j < 0) {
      addition_substraction_result.insert(addition_substraction_result.begin(), vector1.at(i));
    }
    else {
      addition_substraction_result.insert(addition_substraction_result.begin(), vector1.at(i) ^ vector2.at(j));
    }
  }
  return addition_substraction_result;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is due to `.size()` evaluating to an `unsigned` type and the subsequent subtraction happening therefore in `unsigned` arithmetic. (The `int` in an expression containing an `unsigned` and and `int` is converted to an `unsigned`.) This effect is particularly noticeable if the vector is empty.

So *wraparound* effects take the expression value to a large `unsigned` number, and that yields a subscripting error.

The solution is to write an expression of the form

```
i > size() - a
```

as

```
i + a > size()
```